# Changing TextView at runtime

Tags: java, android

My code is like this --
I am trying to fetch my **facebook** profile data
such as *name , email etc* and want to replace it  as 
on my own UI.
I am able to fetch the data , now i want to update my UI 
with a real data .since i am not using `onCreate()` , i am getting `NPE`
when i called `setText(b.getString(key));`
what should i do , since my state is saved on `Bundle b` 
so overrriding `onCreate()` doesnt seems to an option  ??
any help ??

```
package com.android.soapbox;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.android.soapbox.SoapboxApplication.ProfileEventListener;

public class ProfileInfoListner extends Activity  implements ProfileEventListener
{
public TextView mFirstNameTextBox  ;
public TextView mLastNameTextBox  ;


public void ProfileInfoAvailable(Bundle b)
{
 Log.e("Facebook-Example", "Login_sucess"); 
//Go though all the info in the bundle and display

try
{

    for (String key : b.keySet()) 
    {

        if(key.compareTo(SoapboxApplication.FIRST_NAME) == 0)
        {
            Log.e("Facebook-Example", "Log-Printed");   
            //Assuming mFirstNameTextBox points to the textbox on PRofile screen



      if(mFirstNameTextBox!=null)
      {

              Log.e("Facebook-Example", "nnF");
              // NPE
          mFirstNameTextBox.setText(b.getString(key));
      }


        }

}
}
catch(NullPointerException c)
{
    Log.e("ERROR","NPE2"+c.fillInStackTrace());
}

    }   


}
```

Comment: Does it mean that call to b.getString(key) returns null?

Comment: What does your layout XML look like?

Comment: @ Audrius  if u use String name = b. getString(key); then it returns my name , so i have a String , how to set it in my own Ui

Comment: android:paddingTop="20dip"/>
     <TextView
      android:id="@+id/first_name"
      android:textColor="@color/text_foreground"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="60dip"
      android:paddingLeft="20dip"
      android:singleLine="true"
      android:text="Vishesh"/> .............i want to change the text on run time

Comment: Could you please mail the exact error message? Also, are you sure that your are updating the text from the UI thread!?

Comment: @THelper  its just throwin the NPE(catch) , and yes , i saved the sate of UI while calling ProfileInfoAvilable(Bundle B)........also , how could i do it if i chosse to over ride onCreate()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure that no other thread than the UI thread is executing your `ProfileInfoAvailable` method. You can make sure of this by using the following code

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        mFirstNameTextBox.setText(b.getString(key));
    }
}
```

The `onCreate` method of an Activity is always run on the UI thread. If you want to use this, add something like this

```
Intent i = new Intent(CurrentIntent.this, NewIntentToLaunch.class);
i.putExtra("name", userName);
...add more data
startActivity(i);
```

to launch the activity and use something like this

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();
  if (extras != null && extras.containsKey("name")) {
      String userName = this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");
  }
}
```

to read it in your onCreate method.